# Getting an error when using string_agg in sqlserver 2016

Tags: sql-server

I have a sql stored preocedure where I am trying to use the string_agg function.  When I try to create the stored proc I get the error

> Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Procedure MamographyDaily, Line 18 [Batch
> Start Line 7] 'STRING_AGG' is not a recognized built-in function name.

I am running SQLserver 2016 with the SQL 2017 management studio

Comment: `STRING_AGG` was introduced in SQL Server 2017.

Comment: Management studio version is irrelevant - what's relevant is the database compatibility level - and string_agg requires at least 140 - while SQL Server 2016's highest compatibility level is 130.

Comment: What is extremely annoying is that if you put SQL Server 2017 into compatibility mode 130 then it lets you use STRING_AGG, which then fails when you put it on a real 2016 server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`STRING_AGG`** will be supported only If You are using Sql Server version 2017 and higher versions.

Refer: [STRING_AGG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

**Note:** If you are using the below versions you can achieve it by using `FOR XML PATH()`

**Example**:

Sample Data

```
 Field A | Field B
    1       |  A
    1       |  B
    2       |  A
```

Required OutPut

```
1 | AB
2 | A
```

**Query**:

```
select distinct t1.FieldA,
  STUFF((SELECT distinct '' + t2.FieldB
         from yourtable t2
         where t1.FieldA = t2.FieldA
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,0,'') data
from yourtable t1;
```

Comment: Is there an equivalent function in earlier versions or how would you do it?

Comment: you can achieve it by using `FOR XML PATH()` . let me update the answer with an example